# Use Md5 to encypt password in Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, md5

I have a problem encrypting my password using md5. I did the npm install for md5, then imported into my login.ts and applied to the login.data.password like this:

```
import { Md5 } from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';

loginData = { username:'', password:'' };

Md5.hashStr(this.loginData.password);
console.log(this.loginData);
```

And into my html form I have this:

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="loginData.password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
```

How can I use the md5 on the login.data.password?
Thanks

Comment: Note that Md5 is a hash and not secure for hashing passwords

Comment: @Juan thanks juan, but this is the encryption method used into the DB, so I need to use MD5

Comment: So what is your question? Does it work for you? Errors?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko the password is not returning into md5 format

Comment: Just because the DB supplied MD5 does not mean you have to use that for passwords. Are you not concerned with the user security? What kind of person would knowingly put their users at risk?

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably hash your password after user proceeds during registration/login.

If you still want to hash it every time, than you can **create function for hashing the plain password** -

```
  passwordPlain: string;

  hashPassword(plain : string){
    console.log("changed called: " + plain);
    //Hash plain password and save it
    this.loginData.password =  (Md5.hashStr(plain) as string);
  }
```

and **call it every time the input changes** with (ngModelChange) -

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="passwordPlain" (ngModelChange)="hashPassword($event)" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
```

**or (better) after user clicks on a button proceeding login/registration**

```
<button ion-button (click)="hashPassword(passwordPlain)"></button>
```

And as Juan said, note that using s MD5 might not be a good idea.

Comment: error array is not a string so impossible to write data

Comment: sorry, I had a typo in [ngModel]="passwodPlain", should be correct now

Comment: Type string | Int32 array is not assignable to type string

Comment: According to docs - Md5.hashStr should in this case return string, so changing to this should work.

this.loginData.password =  (Md5.hashStr(plain) as string);

Comment: @traiantomescu One nice feature of MD5 password hashing (for the attacker) is that all users with the same password will be known since same passwords have the same hash. Another nice feature (for the attacker) is MD5 is fast so an attacker can go through a common password list quickly. But one might wonder if one should design for the attackers advantage.

Comment: @kjs566 Please Don't help put user's security at risk.